# jQuery.text() doesn't work with textarea elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, return-value

Any reason why jQuery('textarea').text() always returns default value instead of current text when the text area actually has some text and jQuery('textarea')[0].value does return the text? 
Take a look at the [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/qjXgw/4/) to see the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entering a value in an input element (textarea being one of them) doesn't change the markup. `text()` only grabs the text content of the markup. You should use `val()` instead:

```
jQuery('textarea').val()
```

Comment: That's the right answer - you're hired :) I'll mark it as answer when it allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery way to get the text would be:

```
jQuery('textarea').val();
```